# Should questions be cropped to the relevant part after it is clear what the problem was?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've just seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6075926/562769) on SO.
As so often with "what am I doing wrong" questions, the question asker gives information that is - after finding the answer - obviously not relevant.

My question is: Should this question be edited and the irrelevant part be removed?

Comment: The question you reference is no very long as it is.  how do you propose to edit it?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The part about the timestamp is irrelevant  to the problem. The problem was that the question asker forgot to put the assigned variable in quotes. So I would change the first part (over the code) and change the title to something like "Why do my UPDATE queries fail?". If you look at the number of views and the number of upvotes, it seems as if the title of the question / the text of the question might drive a lot of googling-people (like me) to that question, who wanted to know something different which is actually about timestamps.

Comment: So the problem I see there is that the problem was actually simple (forgot to quote arguments) while the question asked (How to insert current timestamp) was almost not related to the problem. I would like to know how we should deal with this type of problem.

Answer (score 3):

When a question is unclear or asking the wrong thing, editing to make it more clear (when you know what the OP is actually asking) is always the right thing to do. However, once a question has answers, it becomes somewhat dicey to edit, as you never want to invalidate an answer.

So, if you edit that question to make the actual issue clear and eliminate the excess noise (or irrelevant content), that is acceptable and encouraged.  However, you can't do it at the expense of the existing content.  If "fixing" the question causes the answers to no longer make any sense, or to be incorrect, or to be answering the wrong question, then editing is generally not the correct course of action as you could be inviting downvotes to the previous answerers.